# Variable's value change affects my entire output in a Spiral Matrix Program

Tags: java, arrays

Below is the working code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class spiralMatrix1 {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of columns and rows in the array");
    int c = in.nextInt();
    int r = in.nextInt(), arr[][] = new int[c][r];
    int k = 1, c1 = 0, c2 = c - 1, r1 = 0, r2 = r - 1, i, j, a = 0;    //i for c and j for r.
    while (k <= r * c) {
        for (i = c1; i <= c2; i++) {
            arr[r1][i] = k++;
        }
        for (j = r1 + 1; j <= r2; j++) {
            arr[j][c2] = k++;
        }
        for (i = c2 - 1; i >= c1; i--) {
            arr[r2][i] = k++;
        }
        for (j = r2 - 1; j >= r1 + 1; j--) {
            arr[j][c1] = k++;
        }
        c1++;
        c2--;
        r1++;
        r2--;
    }
    System.out.println("The Spiral array Is:");
    for (i = 0; i <= c-1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <=r-1; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] +" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.gc();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
} }
```

The output is:

```
Enter the number of columns and rows in the array
5
5
The Spiral array Is:
1 2 3 4 5 
16 17 18 19 6 
15 24 25 20 7 
14 23 22 21 8 
13 12 11 10 9
```

Now if in the above code I change the value of k from 1 to 0 (or better, when I change the beginning value of k in the while loop to be 0 rather than 1 as above), the program gives a ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception. The program and the output is given below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class spiralMatrix1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of columns and rows in the array");
        int c = in.nextInt();
       int r = in.nextInt(), arr[][] = new int[c][r];
        int k = 0, c1 = 0, c2 = c - 1, r1 = 0, r2 = r - 1, i, j, a = 0;    //i for c and j for r.
    while (k <= r * c) {
        for (i = c1; i <= c2; i++) {
            arr[r1][i] = k++;
        }
        for (j = r1 + 1; j <= r2; j++) {
            arr[j][c2] = k++;
        }
        for (i = c2 - 1; i >= c1; i--) {
            arr[r2][i] = k++;
        }
        for (j = r2 - 1; j >= r1 + 1; j--) {
            arr[j][c1] = k++;
        }
        c1++;
        c2--;
        r1++;
        r2--;
    }
    System.out.println("The Spiral array Is:");
    for (i = 0; i <= c-1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <=r-1; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] +" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.gc();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
}
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of columns and rows in the array
5
5
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2147483648
at spiralMatrix1.main(spiralMatrix1.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

This program was created using IntellijIDEA IDE and once the above output was generated.

Answer (score -1):

here is the fixed code

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
class spiralMatrix1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of columns and rows in the array");
        int c = in.nextInt();
       int r = in.nextInt(), arr[][] = new int[c][r];
        int k = 1, c1 = 0, c2 = c - 1, r1 = 0, r2 = r - 1, i, j, a = 0,check=0;    //i for c and j for r.
        if (k<=0)
        {
            check=k+1;
        }
    while (k <= (r * c)-check){
        for (i = c1; i <= c2; i++) {
            arr[r1][i] = k++;
        }
        for (j = r1 + 1; j <= r2; j++) {
            arr[j][c2] = k++;//j=1 c2=4
        }
        for (i = c2 - 1; i >= c1; i--) {
            arr[r2][i] = k++;
        }
        for (j = r2 - 1; j >= r1 + 1; j--) {
            arr[j][c1] = k++;
        }
        c1++;
        c2--;
        r1++;
        r2--;
    }
    System.out.println("The Spiral array Is:");
    for (i = 0; i <= c-1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <=r-1; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] +" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.gc();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
}
}
```

Comment: Just showing the fixed code is *less valuable* than telling us what was broken in the first place.

Comment: The reason is because the loop code was running to many times

Comment: Whatever the reason may be, you need to complete your answer *in* your answer.  Comments aren't going to be the place to do it.